# Import directive not giving access to the class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am including a file like this:

```
#import "BannerPhoneContentController.h"
```

however, when I try to use it like this:

```
bannerContentController = [[BannerPhoneContentController alloc] init];
```

I get the error:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'BannerPhoneContentController';
```

what could be causing the code to seemingly ignore my import?

this is the header for banner content controller.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "BannerContentController.h"

@interface BannerPhoneContentController : BannerContentController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{   
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    UIPageControl *pageControl;
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers;

    // To be used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl
    BOOL pageControlUsed;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPageControl *pageControl;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *viewControllers;

- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender;

@end
```

**EDIT** bannerContentController is of type BannerContentController NOT BannerPhoneContentController. The latter is a subtype of the former. It is definitely worth noting that this exact code works just fine in another app, so it's nothing to do with the code itself - just how it's being included apparently. I'm stumped.

**EDIT** ok found the problem - not sure how to fix it. I generated the preprocessed file and the header file it's included is in fact this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "ContentController.h"

@interface PhoneContentController : ContentController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{   
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    UIPageControl *pageControl;
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers;

    // To be used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl
    BOOL pageControlUsed;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPageControl *pageControl;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *viewControllers;

- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender;

@end
```

note the difference - all the 'Banner's are missing. This is what the file used to look like. However, I've checked and the file that's in the project is the one I posted at the top. I tried cleaning the solution and building again. How can I fix this and why has it happened?

**EDIT** The file that I'm including all this in is part of a code library. I have now created a new project, imported the code library and included all of this in that library once again in exactly the same way. and it works. I have looked over the two projects and the code in question is identical. This must be a project setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks for me like recursive import. Say, `BannerContentController.h` imports `BannerPhoneContentController.h`, and `BannerPhoneContentController.h` imports `BannerContentController.h`.

If it is the case, then you should resolve recursive dependencies. E.g. using forward declaration.

Comment: I have in fact forward declared BannerContentController in the .h, and imported BannerPhoneContentController in the .m. Also this is the same structure as it is in another app which works.

Comment: If you are using new xcode, then you can inspect preprocessed file ("product" menu item iirc)

Comment: If I forward declare BannerPhoneContentController I get - Semantic Issue: Assigning to 'BannerContentController *' from incompatible type 'BannerPhoneContentController *' but how can this be when BannerPhoneContentController inherits directly from BannerContentController?

Comment: product -> generate output -> preprocessed file

Comment: very helpful! thanks. OK so... how odd. the file it's including is the old version with old names (everything's the same minus the 'banner'. checked the actual file and it's the new one so should be working. any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like something is completely wrong. Can you post minimal but complete example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: unfortunately no, it's part of a huge project. I have added one more edit.

Answer (score 0):

does using `@class BannerPhoneContentController` in .h and `#import "BannerPhoneContentController.h"` in .m gives the same result ?

Comment: I get - Receiver 'BannerPhoneContentController' is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist

Comment: Using both `#import` and `@class` in .h file has helped me with receiver warning in the past. Does that help in your case ?

Comment: I get - Semantic Issue: Assigning to 'BannerContentController *' from incompatible type 'BannerPhoneContentController *' but how can this be when BannerPhoneContentController inherits directly from BannerContentController?

Comment: @SirYakalot, in your edit you mention `bannerContentController is of type BannerContentController NOT BannerPhoneContentController.`, then maybe try `alloc`ing into `bannerContentController = [[BannerContentController alloc] init];` instead ?

Comment: I could do that, but it's not what I want to do. This code works in another app so it must be something to do with where I'm putting it.

Comment: only thing other than that i can point out is in your .m i hope there is `#import BannerPhoneContentController` and in .h`@class BannerPhoneContentController`, other than that `alloc` ing the `BannerContentController`, that's all the help i can give, sorry.

Comment: why would I need to forward declare the class in the header if i'm only using it in the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of messing around, and thanks to a comment from Yuras I generated the preprocessed code and realised the problem was that the OLD version of the code was being included.

More useful is WHY. It's just a bug in XCode that happens sometimes when incremental linking is turned on - basically this is where time is saved by only changing the parts of the pre-processed file when the corresponding bits of your code have been altered. Unfortunately, this does not alway work correctly.

The solution, annoyingly, was to delete the files, clean the build, delete the derived data (window / oraniser / projects / project name / delete derived data), restart xcode (possibly also restart your computer, or throw it out of the window and buy a new one) then re-import the files.

XCode can be a real pain...